# Encrypted data as a string

Tags: c, encryption, openssl

I am quite new to encryption and C language so this is maybe an obvious issue, but I find no way of solving the problem.

I am making an application on C and using openssl for encryption in Linux.

I got from this url an example of C code that allows to encrypt and decrypt a string with SHA:
http://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/EVP_Symmetric_Encryption_and_Decryption

```
#include <openssl/conf.h>
#include <openssl/evp.h>
#include <openssl/err.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int arc, char *argv[])
{
  unsigned char *key = "01234567890123456789012345678901";
  unsigned char *iv = "01234567890123456";
  /* Message to be encrypted */
  unsigned char *plaintext = "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog";
  unsigned char ciphertext[128];
  unsigned char decryptedtext[128];
  int decryptedtext_len, ciphertext_len;

  ERR_load_crypto_strings();
  OpenSSL_add_all_algorithms();
  OPENSSL_config(NULL);

  ciphertext_len = encrypt(plaintext, strlen(plaintext), key, iv,ciphertext);

  printf("Ciphertext is:\n");
  BIO_dump_fp(stdout, ciphertext, ciphertext_len);

  EVP_cleanup();
  ERR_free_strings();

  return 0;
}


int encrypt(unsigned char *plaintext, int plaintext_len, unsigned char *key,
  unsigned char *iv, unsigned char *ciphertext)
{
  EVP_CIPHER_CTX *ctx;
  int len;
  int ciphertext_len;

  /* Create and initialise the context */
  if(!(ctx = EVP_CIPHER_CTX_new())) handleErrors();

  if(1 != EVP_EncryptInit_ex(ctx, EVP_aes_256_cbc(), NULL, key, iv))
    handleErrors();

  if(1 != EVP_EncryptUpdate(ctx, ciphertext, &len, plaintext, plaintext_len))
    handleErrors();
  ciphertext_len = len;

  if(1 != EVP_EncryptFinal_ex(ctx, ciphertext + len, &len)) handleErrors();
  ciphertext_len += len;

  EVP_CIPHER_CTX_free(ctx);
  return ciphertext_len;
}
```

I works fine and I have made it work perfectly. What I have seen is that I need to handle that encripted result as a string and append it to a bigger string (actually an SQL command). The code is called like this:

```
ciphertext_len = encrypt(it, strlen(it), key, iv,ciphertext);
strcat(bigstring,ciphertext);
```

When I have tried to do this all the string got altered and unusable. I suposse that the problem comes from binary data being treated as chars, and this includes control characters as  or backspaces.

Is there a way of treating this encrypted data as a String without altering it? 
Should I use another kind of encryption instead?

Comment: Is bigstring also 'unsigned char *'?  One problem with strcat is that if it sees a zero it will think that is the end, so you may want to write your own concatenation function and loop through the appropriate number of times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ciphertext[128]` is not a string and string functions like `strcat(bigstring,ciphertext);` should not be expected to work with it.

In C, "A *string* is a contiguous sequence of characters terminated by and including the first null character."  `ciphertext[128]` may have embedded `'\0'` in it (@James Black) and/or may not have a terminating `'\0'`.

Perform the concatenation another way, maybe:

```
memcpy(bigstring, &ciphertext[bigstring_len], ciphertext_len);
bigstring_len += ciphertext_len;
```

Comment: Looks like this one is working. Now I am getting a different error, but I think that I should investigate before posting it.

Answer (score 2):

If you are working with binary data you must not use str* functions but mem* functions, like memcpy(3) in your case.

For your SQL query, I suggested you to use something else than a string query. For example with mysql I suggest you a prepared statement (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/mysql-stmt-execute.html)

Another solution could be to encode your encrypted (binary) data in hex or base64.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that on printing both the two strings you are trying to concatenate, the answer has no garbage values etc, instead of going to the trouble of using a different encryption(notice the spelling), why not work the other way around and try to write your own concatenate function? It'll work easier for you. I'll be glad to help you with it if you'd like.

Comment: You mean going through the full string copying char by char?. I understand that this way I am copying it "as is". I'll make a try.

Comment: Exactly. I'll be happy to help. Algorithm is quite simple, I have the code to it as well. Find the size of both the strings. Create an array which is the size of both of them combined + 1 (taking into consideration the \0 at the end of each string and the +1 for the \0 of your new concatenated string). Run a loop from 0 to the size of the first string. Copy each character. Then run another loop from the value of the last loop till the size of the seconds string as well as another loop side-by-side to iterate through the characters of the second string (i.e, from 0 to size of second string)

Answer (score 0):

It might not be related to your issue but it would be safer to use:

> strncat

To ensure you are copying not less or more bytes than you want.
Also you may want to double-check your types : strcat takes char* as arguments.